# Using long "e" when pronouncing "the"

Tags: received-pronunciation

I have noticed a regrettable trend toward using the short "e" when pronouncing "the" before words beginning with a vowel: "thuh Earth"; thuh older one". This used to be a cultural symbol (e.g., old movies) of illiteracy and still sounds so to me.  Is there any specific recommendation on this other than taste and pleasing the ear?

Comment: Works the same way as the rule for _a/an_. /ði/ or /ən/ before vowels; /ðə/ or /ə/ before consonants. _An hour, the hour_: /ən'awər, ði'awər/; _a use, the use_: /ə'yus, ðə'yus/.

Answer (score 3):

Meriam-Webster has an excellent suggestion on the pronunciation of "the":

> before consonants usually thə, before vowels usually thē, sometime before vowels also thə; for emphasis before titles and names or to suggest uniqueness often ˈthē

In other words, if you want emphasis, go with the long "e"; and if you feel the pronunciation requires it, use the long "e" before vowels.